# Javascript Function Expected Identifier

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2013

```
angular.module("myapp", [])

   .controller("UsersController", function (testFactory, $scope) {

       $scope.post = function () {

           testFactory.getApiValue("123");

       }

       $scope.change = function () {

           testFactory.getApiValue($scope);
       }   

 .factory("testFactory", function($http) {
        return
          {
           getApiValue: function(token)
             {
                 return $http.post('api/Printers/1');
          }
       }
    })
```

The code works, but Visual Studio tells me there's an `Expected Identifier` error.

Is there anything goes wrong with this code?

Please tell me what I should do to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

For the `getApiValue` function, you're not using the `token` parameter which it is expecting.  This isn't a big problem but you should be able to fix it by removing the unused parameter or using the unused parameter in that function.

Eg:

```
.factory("testFactory", function($http) {
    return
    {
        getApiValue: function() // <---  Token is removed
        {
             return $http.post('api/Printers/1');
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I appreciate your response a lot, I already did that but still giving me the same error

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some more code like where the factory function is actually called?